# 90% Confidence Interval

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

**A random sample of $504$ out of $1600$ students in a school play soccer. How large should the sample of students be if a $90$% confidence interval is desired with a margin of error of $2.2$ percentage points for the proportion of students that play soccer in the school?**

My main problem here is the interpretation of margin of error. The confidence interval I came up with was $\frac{504}{16000}+-1.645\sqrt{\frac{\left(\frac{8631}{40000}\right)}{n}}$. The $+$ and $-$ back to back represent a "plus or minus". $1.645$ is the respective $z$ value for a $90$% confidence interval and $\left(\frac{8631}{40000}\right)$ $=\frac{504}{1600}\left(1-\frac{504}{1600}\right)$ is the variance I calculated.

I thought then that I needed to find a value for $1.645\sqrt{\frac{\left(\frac{8631}{40000}\right)}{n}}$ that was $2.2$% of $\frac{504}{1600}$. This means that I got a final $n$ value of approximately $12158$, but I am not sure if this is what is required in this situation.

If anyone knows if this is the correct approach or not, I would greatly appreciate the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach appears to be correct. You need to find estimates for the sample mean and sample variance and then set the right hand side of your equation ($1.645\sqrt{\frac{s} {n}})$ equal to .022 and solve. However you have made some calculation errors. Recheck your work and see if you can get the answer.

Also note that you can check your answer. Does $1.645 \sqrt{\frac{8631/40000} {12158}}$ equal .022?